# Video section on fullpage.js

Tags: fullpage.js

Is there a way to disable the fullpage.js functionality to move forward or back on scrolling so that moving forward to the next section can be controlled by events? I have a video section that we want the user to watch a video and then move to the next section either by clicking on a skip button or when the video has played all the way through.

Comment: The video section will be the second section on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the document, I remember there are two option you can set. You should set no auto scroll and no scroll first. Then, use `setTimeout()` function to call back allow auto scroll and scroll to other sections.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, just make use of the fullpage.js methods `moveSectionDown`, `movesSectionUp` or even `moveTo`.

Check the [fullpage.js methods on the docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#methods).

Comment: Can I set setAutoScrollingFalse on just one section of the site? Not quite seeing how to do that. Would I have to use something like Waypoints to fire the function when the user enters that section?

Comment: If you want scrollable content you'll have to emulate it using the scrolloverflow option as can be seen in [this example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html).